# Does boundedness in $L^\infty ( 0,T; L^1 (\Omega))$ imply boundedness in $L^\infty (0,T;BV(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, bounded-variation, pointwise-convergence, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $T>0$.

Assume $\lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^\infty ( 0,T; L^1 (\Omega))} \leq C_1$. Does this imply $\lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty (0,T;BV(\Omega))}\leq C_2$ ? Here $C_1,C_2$ are positive constants.

Does it hold if I make the additional assumption on $u \in L^\infty (0,T; W^{1,1})$?

Because then by definition of this space:

$u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega)) \subset L^\infty(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$,

$\nabla u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$.

Then it holds:
$\lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty (0,T; BV (\Omega))} = \lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty (0,T; W^{1,1})} = \lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T;L^1(\Omega))} + \lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T;L^1(\Omega))} \leq \tilde{C} \nabla u \rVert_{L^\infty(0,T;L^1(\Omega))} + C_1$
and since $u \in L^\infty(0,T;L^1(\Omega))$, this implies $\lVert u \rVert_{L^\infty (0,T; BV (\Omega))} \leq C_2$.

Where I used the Poincaré inequality and the assumption $\lVert \nabla u \rVert_{L^\infty ( 0,T; L^1 (\Omega))} \leq C_1$.
Is this proof correct?

Comment: What (semi?-)norm are you using on $BV(\Omega)$?

Comment: As stated, this might not true: take $u_n(x,t):=n$.

Comment: I am using the norm $\lVert u \rVert_{BV} = \lVert u \rVert_{L^1} + \lVert Du \rVert$, where $Du$ is the distributional derivative and $\lVert Du \rVert$ its total variation.

Comment: I just edited my question, does it hold if I make the additional assumption on $u$, i.e. $u \in L^\infty (0,T; W^{1,1})$?

Comment: The comment by daw is still valid for this revised version.

Comment: But I don't see where my proof does not work. Do you have an idea?